# Java Calendar scheduling events

Tags: java, events, calendar, schedule

In my application i want to schedule the start of processing. In two ways first on a preset date or say like every Monday. In the case of a single date i can watch the time on a tread and start processing but when two are mixed i can't come up with a good solution.

My initial thought was when application boots up i can schedule events to calendar and check if there is job to do every min or so, that would work for both single date and every week case turns out i can not use the calendar that way.

What is a good way to solve this?

Comment: Joda Time is certainly more accurate than java.util.Date, but it doesn't seem to have scheduling functionality built in. The questioner may be willing to trade off the inaccuracy of timing for the ease of having something that already does the scheduling for them.

Comment: Yeah, I re-read the question and deleted the comment.

Answer (score 2):

[Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is an open-source job scheduling component written in Java, you might want to check that out.
Its features range from simple timers to full-blown [CRON expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRON_expression), and it's used extensively by the JBoss AS.

Answer (score 1):

Look at java.util.Timer. It allows you to schedule tasks for execution at a specified time on a background thread, and it support recurring events.